# How to sort a List of objects by property type

Tags: java

I want to break the list of tasks below, into smaller lists, based on the assignedTo property on the task.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Task t Where t.status!='Completed' AND t.delayTaskUntilDate==null AND t.time<= DATEADD(GETDATE()-3)")
List<Task> findStaticTasks();
```

I am not sure if I can use Sublist() or if I should use a Comparator, or create a sorting algorithm?

If I need to make a sorting algorithm with a for loop to compare task[i].getAssignedTo() to task[i+1].getAssignedTo() and then push it to a new list, what is the syntax to do that, as the above syntax is not only for arrays, but also doesn't properly access the propert?

Any guidance in the right direction of how to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `findStaticTasks().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Task::getAssignedTo))`

Comment: @shmosel That's a worthy answer imo

Comment: @shmosel, doesn't this just sort it in the current list? I need to actually break it out from one giant list, into different smaller lists.

Comment: No, this breaks it out into separate lists.